# Generating QR code which can be read only by my app

Tags: qr-code

I have developed a QR code reader and a scanner using the ZXings source.
Now i want to embed an info in the qr code which only my reader can
read and no other reader can read . Is this feasible ?

I basically don't want the public to know as to what the qr code contains other than my personal group of friends who would use my qr reader to find what is present in the qr code. 
When a user tries to read the qr code  with a reader other than my reader , he should be getting garbage data and not the actual data present in the qr code.

QR Driod seems to have something like  this in place by using a password protection (http://qrdroid.com/blog/author/droidla/page/2) but i could not figure out how they have done that .

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249442/secure-encrypted-qr-codes ?

Answer (score 4):

There are two approaches you could take which spring to mind;

1. **Encrypt the information** You could implement a system (which, as you say, QRDroid does, along with many other such apps) whereby you use the following process; **1** take the information you want to put into your QR, **2** encrypt that information using a standard protocol (Wikipedia can help you get started here if you're completely in the dark about such things) - this can be password protected, or by some other means.  Depends partly on the level of secrecy you want here... **3** encode the new encrypted information into a QR code.  At the other end, the app reads the QR code, then decrypts it and voila.
2. **Develop a different QR-style protocol?** This is clearly *much* more ambitious, and wouldn't necessarily provide any theoretical security (unless you implemented part 1 somehow as well).  It *would*, however, result in a code which was unreadable by other standard apps, since they wouldn't know how to interpret the pattern they were seeing.  That said, a lot of careful thought went into developing QR as a useful approach, so this would be an exercise I'd suggest considering only for the techy joy of taking it on :D

Going back to point 1, if you want your app only to be able to read things, but not have to have a user enter a password or anything, you could use a single fixed 'password' that the app knew (perhaps even hard-coded in, at it's most basic).  It would use this automatically to encrypt and decrypt at each end.  This would obviously represent a massive security flaw under close scrutiny, but if you just want something that'll keep your info reasonably secret *from other QR apps currently available*, this would do the job.  In this case, you'd really just be encoding your information rather than encrypting, I suppose, but in a way that other apps don't know how to *de*code as standard.

Comment: Been a long time but @unwitting, how would one go about implementing #2?  I've been searching everywhere on how to initiate that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt the data before putting it into the QR code, using a key only your app knows.

Comment: Yes, but an attacker could look into the app, and extract the key from the code :) Any "secret" is really secret if on a device.

Comment: @LucaPerico really not* a secret.. And yes, the decryption should be server-side.